# Azure storage blob downloads old file version

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am facing the issue while downloading of azure blob file with old file being downloaded.Here are the steps.

While uploading.. following code is used.

```
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileNamePrefix);
                if (blobClient.Exists())
                {
                    await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
                }
```

While above process works well, and in blob storage, i see updated file, if the same blob already existed.

After this is done, If i perform download operation.

```
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(mstream);
```

I still see old file. So even though, new file exists in storage, the operation gives me old file.

It's baffling why it happening, but any idea's would be useful.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to use BlobClient for Delete of snapshot. await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots, null, default);

Comment: i thought it did work. but it doesn't the download part still downloads the older version.in storage the file appears overwritten perfectly.

Comment: @MandarJogalekar  which version of the blob package you're using? and how big is the blob file? and you'd better provide a sample code which can be used to produce the issue, I think there might be a minor error in your code.

Comment: i use azure.storage.blobs 12.7.0 .
blob file i test with is very small 5-10 Kbs. . I provide a code above in the question already

Comment: @MandarJogalekar what does the return flag show? True or false? Also, there is delay in clearing snapshot. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.deleteifexists?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_DeleteIfExists_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_DeleteSnapshotsOption_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_. Also, try to put few seconds delay in upload and see what happens?

Comment: @MandarJogalekar, I cannot repro the issue. The only possible reason I can think of is that you're running the uploading code and downloading code at the same time, during this case, when the uploading is in uncommitted status, it will cause the issue. If possible, can you please write a demo project and upload to github, then we can use your code to repro/fix the issue.

Comment: or is there some reason that you're using 2 different blobclient which points 2 different blob file(like 2 blobs with same name, but in different container)?

Answer (score 0):

Putting it here so anyone else faces problem. Will help them.

You have to use BlobClient for Delete of snapshot. await blobClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots, null, default);

*Please mark this as answer for others :)*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior you have. After logging out and log back in Azure, I did see the updated file as expected.